# How can a Beast Master ranger's animal companion overcome resistance to non-magical attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, damage-resistance

The 5e Beast Master ranger's animal companion has a rather significant drawback in some mid- or high-level campaigns. Because animal companions never gain the magical attack feature and due to the lack of a *Magic Fang*-type spell in 5e, there are particularly deadly fights in which an animal companion may not able to contribute much damage, *if any*.

**Is there any way, as a dedicated Beast Master, to bypass this deficiency and grant a magical attack to your animal companion, even briefly?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## At ranger level 7, the animal companion's attacks are treated as magical (as of the 2018 errata)

Per the [2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), the [Beast Master ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#BeastMaster)'s 7th-level feature, Exceptional Training, has been edited to add this benefit:

> Beginning at 7th level, on any of your turns when your beast companion doesn’t attack, you can use a bonus action to command the beast to take the Dash, Disengage, or Help action on its turn.
>
> **In addition, the beast's attacks now count as magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage.**